# Why is this C program segfaulting at this location?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on making a C program that basically can take a sentence and count how many times each word appears in it. I've made a stripped down version that reproduces the issue exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

typedef struct testStrut{ 
    char * string; 
    int uses; 
}word; 

void grow(); 

int main(){
    int i; 
    int count = 1; 
    word ** words; 

    words = (word **) malloc(count * sizeof(word *)); 
    words[0] = (word *) malloc(sizeof(word)); 

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Re-looping i: %d \n", i); 
        printf("words[0]->string = %s \n", words[0]->string); 
        grow("TEST", words, &count); 
    }

    printf("Done."); 
    return 0; 
}

void grow(char * str, word ** words, int * count){
    word ** tmp; 

    tmp = realloc(words, (*count) * sizeof(word *)); 

    if(tmp){
        tmp[(*count)-1] = malloc(sizeof(word)); 
        tmp[(*count)-1]->string = malloc(strlen(str)+1); /*+1 for null terminator as pointed out */  
        strcpy(tmp[(*count)-1]->string, str); 
        tmp[(*count)-1]->uses = 1;     
        words = tmp; 
        (*count)++; 
    } else{
        printf("Failure to allocate. \n"); 
        exit(0); 
    }
    printf("Count: %d and word[0] %s \n", (*count), str); 
}
```

As well as the output from a run:

```
Re-looping i: 0
words[0]->string = (null)
Count: 2 and word[0] TEST
Re-looping i: 1
words[0]->string = TEST
Count: 3 and word[0] TEST
Re-looping i: 2
words[0]->string = TEST
Count: 4 and word[0] TEST
Re-looping i: 3
words[0]->string = TEST
Count: 5 and word[0] TEST            /*Prints it fine? */ 
Re-looping i: 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)     /*Suddenly unable to print it? */
```

I'm not understanding why between ending the grow function and re-going through the loop the value of words[0]->str is suddenly lost. Is there something I'm missing?

[I do know that I should be freeing anything I malloc.I also realize my method prototype isn't the correct one but I just wanted to make a quick program that demonstrated my issue]

Comment: Hint: What does `void f(int i) {i = 7;} int main() {int x = 5; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` print? Now change `int i` to `word ** words`, and `int x` to `word ** words`, and `7` to `realloc(...)`

Comment: Another mistake is that you've made a wrong "string" allocation, length of a string is `strlen(str)+1` to take the NUL terminating char in account.

Comment: Your example prints 5 since i is passed by value, isn't when I pass word ** words it a pointer so any modifications would be reflected in main as well?

Thanks Jean for catching that! My bad, I've edited to reflect that change.

Comment: It suddenly stops working when realloc decided to return a pointer to a new memory location.

Comment: Is there any reasoning behind that? What's the proper way to fix this/do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Nateb1121 you have to properly use the pointer returned by realloc. As immbis said, you're not returning the value correctly.

Comment: Do note that giving null pointer to `%s` has **undefined behaviour**, also on first iteration your `->string` pointer is **uninitialized**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Apologies, I wrote this program in a haste and didn't remember to correctly initialize that. I meant this to quickly serve as a demonstration.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
words = tmp;
```

This statement has no effect outside of the function.

Since realloc may (or may not) return a new pointer to another memory location, you code may work a few times before crashing.

You should use a word*** instead of the word** parameter or simply return the new pointer:

```
word** grow(char * str, word ** words, int * count){
    word ** tmp; 

    tmp = realloc(words, (*count) * sizeof(word *)); 

    if(tmp){
        tmp[(*count)-1] = malloc(sizeof(word)); 
        tmp[(*count)-1]->string = malloc(strlen(str)+1); /*+1 for null terminator as pointed out */  
        strcpy(tmp[(*count)-1]->string, str); 
        tmp[(*count)-1]->uses = 1;   
        (*count)++; 
    } else{
        printf("Failure to allocate. \n"); 
        exit(0); 
    }
    printf("Count: %d and word[0] %s \n", (*count), str); 
    return tmp;
}
```

And call it this way:

```
words = grow("TEST", words, &count);
```

Comment: What would be the proper way to assure that the value of word is overwritten to be the address of tmp? It seems I'm mistaken in my assumption that word ** words is passed as a pointer and that any modifications to it would be reflected outside the function...

Comment: @Nateb1121 You can simply return the new pointer as value instead of trying to update a function parameter. Otherwise a pointer to word** (i.e. word***) would be necessary.

Comment: Oh, duh! Apologies for my line of questioning but if I'm understanding right because  word ** words is a pointer I can change the contents of that pointer and have it reflected outside the grow() function, however I can NOT change the actual place where words points and expect it to have any effect outside grow()?

Comment: @Nateb1121 Yes, a pointer is a variable containing a value (an address to a memory location), you can change the data at that memory location (which would reflect outside a function), but if you change the value of the variable (the pointer) it will only affect the scope of the variable (here the function).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I feel silly for overlooking that!

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration of the for loop the following line is accessing uninitialized memory.

```
printf("words[0]->string = %s \n", words[0]->string);
```

You have also declared

```
void grow();
```

but the actual signature ie

```
void grow(char * str, word ** words, int * count)
```

You first need to call `grow` before that line ie. You are also `realloc` and assuming that the pointer `words` in main points to the original pointer.

Try this. I've simplified a little bit...

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
typedef struct testStrut{ 
  char * string; 
  int    uses; 
} word; 

void grow(const char *str, word *words, int count); 

int main(){
  int i;  
  word * words; 
  printf("sizeof word == %zu\n", sizeof(word));
  assert(sizeof(word) == 16);
  words    = malloc(sizeof(word)); 
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("Re-looping i: %d \n", i); 
    grow("TEST", words, i); 
    printf("words[0]->string = %s \n", words[0].string); 
  }
  printf("Done."); 
  return 0;  
}
void grow(const char * str, word *words, int count){
  word ** tmp; 
  int idx = count - 1;
  printf("size == %zu\n", count * sizeof(word));
  tmp = realloc(words, count * sizeof(word)); 
  size_t str_len = strlen(str); 
  if(tmp != NULL) {
    tmp[idx]         = malloc(sizeof(word*)); 
    tmp[idx]->string = malloc(str_len + 1); 
    strcpy(tmp[idx]->string, str); 
    tmp[idx]->string[4] = '\0';
    tmp[idx]->uses = 1;
  } else{
    printf("Failure to allocate. \n");
    exit(0);
  }
  printf("Count: %d and word[0] %s \n", count, str);
}
```

Comment: I realize that now in my haste to make this, however, would that be causing the issue I'm experiencing?

I understand I'm now using the correct method prototype, this is just a quick dirty example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: count is incremented each time the grow method is executed by the (*count)++ line.

Comment: `void grow();` is allowed, it just means that the compiler won't validate the argument types for you. Fortunately OP used the right types in the call. Of course it is a good idea to use the prototype so that the compiler helps you out.

Comment: @Nateb1121 yes, `words[0]->string` is an uninitialized pointer, so it is quite likely that trying to print a string from where it points will cause a segfault

Comment: @M.M If so then why would it still successfully run through the loop 4 times before segfaulting?

Comment: maybe the random junk happened to be different the 5th time. who knows?